# Easiest way to get a crash dump from a customer?

Tags: crash-dumps

My application is crashing on a customer's machine. I'd like to get him to send me a crash dump.  What is the simplest, least-painful way I can ask him to do this for me?  Command line utils, for example, will simply not work here.

I've heard tale that setting a registry key in Windows somewhere will cause it to save a crash dump at a location you specify.  I have not been able to find this mysterious key though.

Comment: You might want to identify the operating system with the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

So assumming Windows 7, here's one site that describes how to generate crash dumps:
http://kb.acronis.com/content/38195

This uses the built-in Windows Error Reporting (WER)